# Exercise 3.16 in Brezis' Functional Analysis

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

I'm doing Exercise 3.16 from the Brezis' book, and here's my attempted answer, not sure if it's correct or not.

> Let $E$ be a Banach space.
>
> 1. Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence in $E^⋆$ such that for every $x \in E, ⟨f_n, x⟩$ converges to
>    a limit. Prove that there exists some $f \in E^⋆$ such that $f_n \stackrel{*}{\rightharpoonup} f$ in $\sigma(E^⋆, E).$
> 2. Assume here that $ E $ is reflexive. Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $E$ such that for every
>    $f \in E^⋆,⟨f, x_n⟩$ converges to a limit. Prove that there exists some $x \in E$ such
>    that $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ in $\sigma(E, E^⋆).$
> 3. Construct an example in a nonreflexive space $E$ where the conclusion of 2 fails.

---

1.Since $\forall x\in E,f_n(x)$ has a limit in $\mathbb{R},$ which may be denoted $f_x,$ and defining the mapping $f:E\to\mathbb{R} f(x)=f_x,$ it is clear that there is $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x), \forall x\in E,$ and the next step is simply to prove that $f\in E^*.$
I found the following corollary in the book.

**Corollary 2.5:**

> Let $G$ be a Banach space and let $B^⋆$ be a subset of $G^⋆.$
>
> Assume that
> for every $ x\in G $ the set $⟨B^⋆, x⟩ = \{⟨f, x⟩; f \in B^⋆\}$ is bounded (in $\mathbb{R}$).
>
> Then $B^⋆$ is bounded.

By Cauchy's convergence theorem,we know that every convergent column is bounded on the complete n.v.s. So we have that for $\forall x\in E,f_n(x)$ is bounded, and by corollary,$f_n$ is a bounded sequence on $E^*,$ i.e., there exists $M>0,$ such that $||f_n||\leq M.$ Then $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty }f_n(x)\leq M||x||.$ Therefore, $f\in E^*.$

2.The problem is equivalent to proving that $\forall f\in E^*,f(x_n)\to f(x),$ Since $E$ is a reflexive space, it can be made $E\cong E^{**}$ by the canonical mapping $J.$ Then there is $(x_n)\in E\cong (x_n'')\in E^{**}$ which makes $f(x_n)=x_n''(f),\forall f \in E^*,$ the problem is equivalent to $\forall f\in E^*,x_n''\in E^{**},x_n''(f)$ converges to a limit. From 1 it is clear that exists $x''\in E^{**}$ such that $x_n''(f)\to x''(f),\forall f\in E^*,$ and again there is through $J$ there $E\cong E^{**},$ it is known that there exists $x\in E$ such that $x_n\rightharpoonup x$

3.By the hint, take $E=c_0,$ i.e. the subspace of $\ell ^\infty$ i.e.
$$c_0=\{x\in \ell ^\infty;\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k=0\}$$
Take $x_n = (1, 1, ..., \underset{(n)}{1}, 0, 0, ...).\forall f\in E^*=\ell^1$ have
$f=(f_1,f_2,... ,f_n,...)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|f_k|<\infty.$

So we have $f(x_n)\to\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_k<\infty.$But clearly there is no $x\in c_0$ such that $f(x) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_k.$